# Fatal Error by Java Runtime when running libgdx lwjgl

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, lwjgl

I'm trying to use libGDX for the first time and I've downloaded the lwjgl library and am trying to simply open a window and a fatal error gets detected by the Java runtime environment. I was getting a different error:

```
JavaVM WARNING: JAWT_GetAWT must be called after loading a JVM
_NSJVMLoadLibrary: NSAddLibrary failed for /libjawt.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: lookup of function JAWT_GetAWT failed. Exit
AL lib: ReleaseALC: 1 device not closed
```

but after adding:

```
System.loadLibrary("jawt");
```

It changed to the runtime error.

The code is:

```
   import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;

public class GameStarter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("jawt");
        new LwjglApplication(new Game(), "Chess", 480, 320, false);
    }

}
```

And the error file says:

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00000001274d4388, pid=1186, tid=5891

 JRE version: 7.0_25-b15
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.25-b01 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
 Problematic frame:
 C  [liblwawt.dylib+0xe388]  JNI_OnLoad+0x96

 Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

 An error report file with more information is saved as:
 /Users/simonwatkins/Documents/workspace/Chess/hs_err_pid1186.log

 If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
 The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
 See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
```

I'd really appreciate any help so I can learn this great tool! 
Sorry if I've done anything wrong in the asking of this question - first post.